# Using Non-Standard Python Install

Tags: python, centos

I recently attempted to upgrade our Python install on a CentOS server from 2.4.3 to 2.7, however it lists 2.4.3 as the newest stable release.  This is a problem because I have a Python program that requires at least 2.7 to run properly.  After contacting support they installed Python 2.7 in a separate directory, however I'm not sure how to access this version.  Anytime I try to run the python program it uses the 2.4.3 version.  I have looked into changing the PythonHome variable, but can't get it to work correctly.  Is there anything I can do via the command line or inside the program itself to specify which Python version I want to use?

Comment: The script probably has a startup script or configuration, you can change the path there.

Comment: did you try running it with `python27 script.py`?

Comment: @agf  I get this response: "python27: command not found".  I'm guessing this is because Python 2.7 is installed in a non-standard directory.  Specifically its in /opt/python27/

Comment: Try `sudo ln -s /opt/python27/python /usr/local/bin/python27` then `python27 script.py`. I don't know exactly where the Python binary is actually installed so it might need to be something like `sudo ln -s /opt/python27/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python27`. If it works I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the full path to the python executable (i.e. `/opt/python27/python`) rather than using a bare `python` command. Alternatively, place `/opt/python27/` on your `PATH` earlier than `/usr/local/bin` (where the `python` command is presumably already present, you can check with `which python`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you ask your support team to build a separate RPM for Python2.7 and have it installed in a separate location and not conflicting with the OS version. I've done this before it was great to have a consistent Python released across my RHEL3, 4, and 5 systems.

Next, I'd suggest you use the following for your sh-bang (first line) "#!/bin/env python2.7" and then ensure your PATH includes the supplemental Python install path. This way, your script stays the same as you run it on your workstation, with it's own unique path to python2.7, and the production environment as well.